# Eclipse Maven: run test with spring profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I want to run maven with different profile but it seems not working. 
I created 2 differents java class for my JPAConfiguration :

JPAConfiguration.class and JPAConfigurationTest.class

```
@Configuration 
@Profile({"dev"}) 
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true) 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.jle.athleges.model.repository", "com.jle.athleges.security.repository" }) 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.jle.athleges.model.services", "com.jle.athleges.security.services" }) 
public class JpaConfiguration { 

    @Bean 
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException { 
        System.out.println("use dev"); 
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(); 
        builder.setName("dev"); 
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException { 

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(); 
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); 

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter); 
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.jle.athleges.model.entity", "com.jle.athleges.security.entity"); 
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); 
        factory.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        return factory.getObject(); 

    } 

    @Bean 
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) { 
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException { 
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()); 
        return txManager; 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() { 
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    } 

} 

@Configuration 
@Profile({"test"}) 
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true) 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.jle.athleges.model.repository", "com.jle.athleges.security.repository" }) 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.jle.athleges.model.services", "com.jle.athleges.security.services" }) 
public class JpaConfigurationTest { 

    @Bean 
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException { 
        System.out.println("use test"); 
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(); 
        builder.setName("test"); 
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException { 

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(); 
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); 

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter); 
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.jle.athleges.model.entity", "com.jle.athleges.security.entity"); 
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource()); 
        factory.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        return factory.getObject(); 

    } 

    @Bean 
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) { 
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException { 
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); 
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()); 
        return txManager; 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() { 
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    } 

}
```

In my pom.xml, I have this  :

```
<project> 

… 

<dependencies> 

… 

</dependencies> 

    <profiles> 
        <profile> 
            <id>dev</id> 
            <activation> 
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> 
            </activation> 
        </profile> 
        <profile> 
            <id>test</id> 
        </profile> 
    </profiles> 


    <build> 
        <finalName>AthleGes</finalName> 
        <pluginManagement> 
            <plugins> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <source>1.8</source> 
                        <target>1.8</target> 
                        <debug>true</debug> 
                    </configuration> 
                </plugin> 

            </plugins> 
        </pluginManagement> 
        <plugins> 
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version> 
                <configuration> 
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
                </configuration> 
            </plugin> 
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version> 
                <configuration> 
                    <jettyEnvXml>src/test/resources/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml> 
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds> 
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey> 
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort> 
                </configuration> 
                <executions> 
                    <execution> 
                        <id>start-jetty</id> 
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>run</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds> 
                            <daemon>true</daemon> 
                        </configuration> 
                    </execution> 
                    <execution> 
                        <id>stop-jetty</id> 
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>stop</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                    </execution> 
                </executions> 
            </plugin> 
        </plugins> 
    </build> 

</project>
```

And finally, I have a test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test","dev"}) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JpaConfigurationTest.class, JpaConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class }) 
@TestExecutionListeners({  
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, 
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, 
        }) 
public class MemberServiceImpTest { 

    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberServiceImpTest.class); 

    @Autowired 
    private MemberService memberService; 

    @Autowired 
    private MemberRepository repository; 

    @Before 
    public void setUp(){ 
        repository.deleteAll(); 
    } 

    @Test 
    public void saveMember() { 

        log.debug("Start saveMember"); 
        Member a = new Member(); 
        a.setFirstname("aaa"); 
        a.setLastname("hhh"); 
        a.setId(0L); 

        Assert.assertNotNull(memberService.save(a)); 

        log.debug("End saveMember"); 
    } 

    @Test 
    public void getAllMembers() { 
        log.debug("Start getAllMember"); 

        long sizeBefore = repository.count(); 
        Member a = new Member(); 
        a.setFirstname("aaa"); 
        a.setLastname("hhh"); 
        a.setId(2L); 

        Member b = new Member(); 
        b.setFirstname("aaa"); 
        b.setLastname("hhh"); 
        b.setId(1L); 
        memberService.save(a); 
        memberService.save(b); 

        Assert.assertEquals(memberService.getAll().size(),sizeBefore + 2); 
        log.debug("End getAllMember"); 
    } 
}
```

When I run my unit test from Eclipse, it is working fine. If I move the profile in the test class from dev to test and from test to dev, it is working. I mean the test pass and the displayed message "use dev" or "use test" is displayed.

I want to run the tests from maven (with m2e) and I created this configuration :

[image: Eclipse-Maven-Configuration]

But when I change the profile, test is always started.

I tried to activate profile from Maven -> Select Maven Profile but I have been the same result.

I miss something but I don't know what. I don't understand.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As per your configuration @ActiveProfiles, both the profiles will be activated during your test execution. If you want to control the active spring profile for test cases through maven, then I would suggest you to remove @ActiveProfiles annotation from your test class and specify spring.profiles.active as a system property. You could do it using either of the following ways:

**Set it in the maven surefire plugin configurtion:**

```
<project>
    <properties>
       <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
      </profile>
      <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
      </profile>
    </profiles>

       <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

You can simply run maven test as you are doing already by passing spring.profiles.active parameter without the profile name. Profile will be activated automatically using value of the property spring.profiles.active

**OR**

**Pass it to surefire plugin through maven parameter during execution like:**

mvn -DargLine="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help.
I don't really use (for now) maven in command but with eclipse. So I don't run directly lvn command, I use m2e.

It is not working completely with all solutions : 
1) I removed @ActiveProfile in JUnit Test and I added spring.profiles.active (dev) in Eclipse Run Configuration Environment. (it works)
2) I updated pom.xml by adding property spring.profiles.active in settings and it works.
3) I configured profiles with dev, test and surfire plugin and removing settings property but when I run maven with the environment, it don't use the param defined.

Comment: Finally, I need to define spring.profiles.active in each maven configuration. It is working but nor really as I want. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running with different profiles regularly for testing purposes on Eclipse, you can select the active profile directly in Eclipse without modifying the pom.

[Select active profile under Maven > Select Maven Profiles...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir1sJ.png)